# Erro no algoritmo deBoyer-Moore

Tags: c

Estou estudando como contar quantas vezes uma string aparece na outra, e encontrei esse site [Link do site](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/strma.html#boyermoore), nele tem o algoritmo deBoyer-Moore, que encontra número de ocorrências de a em b, mas só que quando eu passo os valores a função retorna 1, quando deveria retornar 6, estou cometendo algum erro na chamada da função

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int trivial ( char a[], int m,  char b[], int n)
{
   int i, j, k, ocorre = 0;
    for (k = m; k <= n; ++k)
    {
        for (i = m, j = k; i >= 1; --i, --j)
         if (a[i] != b[j]) break;
       if (i < 1) ++ocorre;
   }
  return ocorre;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char a[] = "78954";
    char b[] = "7895478954789547895447895478954";
    int tamA = strlen(a);
    int tamB = strlen(b);
    int resultado = trivial(a, tamA, b, tamB);
    printf("%d\n", resultado);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Seu código nem compila.

Comment: Olá maneiro olhe aqui o link https://ideone.com/T0ZiLy ele compilou de boas

Comment: É, na hora de colar comeu algo aqui. mas ainda não tem nada na sua pergunta que indique sobre o problema, o que você quer, dá uma informação, jogar o código e mandar a gente se virar pra resolver o problema não é legal. Alias vou te falar que você continua cometendo os mesmos erros e continua não conseguindo resolver os problemas, isto significa que não está aprendendo e precisa mudar a metodologia que de aprendizado.

Comment: ok, sei que você não gosta de falar de metodologia, mas poderia me dar uma dica metodologia de aprendizado

Comment: Faça um curso, procure livros, estruture o aprendizado, faça de forma continua, só passe para algo mais complexo quando dominar o que é mais básico. Eu tenho certeza que você não consegue explicar o que este código está fazendo. Ele é complexo demais para seu conhecimento atual. Está queimando etapas e não está aprendendo porque conhecimento se constrói uma passo de cada vez, pula um e tudo fica mais difícil. Eu e outras pessoas damos respostas que mostram formas melhores de fazer, você continua fazendo do jeito desorganizado e ignora o que foi passado. Aí não tem metodologia que dê certo.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado